# VLookup with multiple “col_index_num”s

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stuck on the correct syntax for writing a VLookup in VBA where you want to return multiple columns.

Usually the you use {2,3,4,5} however VBA does not accept this as valid.

```
Set Sheet1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set Sheet2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Set Sheet3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)

result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheet2.Range("A2"), Sheet1.Range("AA9:AF20"), {2,3,5,6,7,8,9}, False)
```

I have done numerous searches on the web for this solution, but there isn't a clear answer to how to properly syntax  `{2,3,5,6,7,8,9}`

Comment: Why do you want to do this, as a matter of interest? It's better IMO to use `Match` to check the value you want is there, and then use `Rows`  to return the whole row if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WorksheetFunction` can't perform an array formula. `Evaluate` can.

So

```
sFormula = "VLOOKUP(" & Sheet2.Range("A2").Address(external:=True) & "," & Sheet1.Range("AA9:AF20").Address(external:=True) & ",{2,3,5,6,7,8,9},FALSE)"

result = Evaluate(sFormula)
```

But from  `AA` to `AF` are only 6 columns. so trying to get column 7,8,9 will lead to an error.

So maybe

```
sFormula = "VLOOKUP(" & Sheet2.Range("A2").Address(external:=True) & "," & Sheet1.Range("AA9:AI20").Address(external:=True) & ",{2,3,5,6,7,8,9},FALSE)"

result = Evaluate(sFormula)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through as

```
sub Mlookup()
    dim i as integer
    dim res 

    for i = 1 to 5
        res = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheet2.Range("A2"), Sheet1.Range("AA9:AF20"), i, False)
        sheet1.range("A"&i").value = res
    next i

end sub
```